# Kiosk mode in Node-webkit not working?

Tags: manifest, node-webkit

I'm trying out the basic tutorial for [Node-webkit.](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)
The manifest includes options to make your app go fullscreen or even in kiosk mode, which is exactly what I need.

Sadly, the app does not open in fullscreen or kiosk mode no matter what I put in the manifest file.

I'm on Mac OS, I downloaded "node-webkit.app". I am compressing my manifest.json and index.html into a "app.nw" zipfile, and then opening that with the mac app. Is there anything I'm overlooking?

My manifest file:

```
   {
      "name": "mydemo",
      "main": "index.html",
      "window": {
        "title": "baby's first node-webkit demo",
        "resizable":"false",
        "show_in_taskbar":"true",
        "fullscreen":"true",
        "kiosk":"true"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I'm answering my own question here... don't use:

```
"kiosk":"true"
```

Instead use

```
"kiosk":true
```

I was under the impression JSON always uses quotes around properties...

Comment: This helped us a lot, thank you :). But no, JSON properties can be integers, arrays, objects as well as strings. And booleans, yeah.